# Getting 404 with locall IIS 7 served page

Tags: asp.net, iis

My setup:

Vista 64-bit PC (my local PC)
IIS 7 obviously
VS 2008

I setup a new "Application" manually under the IIS default site.  It's running.
The application is pointing to the correct directory (where my default.aspx exists)
I've setup this same exact setup on our dev server running Server 2008 and it runs fine

But for me, when I go to http://localhost/MyAppName I get a 404 not found.

I have no clue why.

So since that did not work and still got a 404, then I tried instead changing from using the VS web server to using IIS in my web project properties in the "Web" tab in VS 2008.  Then clicked the "Create Virtual Directory" button and it created a new Application in IIS for me.  Same thing though.  If I go to that address, I get a 404 on my local machine where it's running.

Comment: What happens if you create a new site instead of an app/virtual directory?

Comment: Going to uninstall / Reinstall IIS...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had not installed the IIS 6 functionality of IIS in Vista.  I did not know it still used legacy features in IIS 7 to run sites locally....I guess.  Not sure why but I guess it uses these IIS6 features.  Will have to research why it's dependent on this stuff.

Comment: would be nice if there was a decent book out there on IIS 7.  Any sites I see don't really give you any specific information either...the resources kinda suck.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the home directory to look for "default.aspx" as the default page?

Comment: well, when I look at the default document area, default.aspx is in there, it's there by default after installing IIS and enabling asp.net and always is there....if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check:

First, look at your access logs to see exactly what request is getting logged.

Check your IIS config - you may have a default.aspx page, but is IIS configured to use that as one of the default pages?  If you go to http://localhost/AppName/default.aspx do you still get a 404?

If you put a static test.html file in the same directory, can you access it?

These should all help determine the cause.

Comment: (If you go to http://localhost/AppName/default.aspx do you still get a 404?)  Yes

Comment: (If you put a static test.html file in the same directory, can you access it?) No